# Upload beta package - how to bypass or speed up tests execution

Tags: unit-test, managed-package, code-coverage, upload, beta-managed-package

We have our huge managed package (1st generation, i.e. classic one) and every time when we upload new beta version (even with just a few fixes) it takes up to 3 hours for the whole process to complete - tests execution takes the most part of it.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to bypass/suppress tests execution when uploading beta package. We'd like to have our beta version ready ASAP to install it in QA org, run smoke and start manual testing. And after that we might run apex tests post factum on packaging org to catch additional problems with logic.

When it comes to ordinary code deployment (change sets, ant whatever) SF does not enforce tests execution re sanboxes. And even for production deployment there are some additional options like quick deploy or running just subset of tests to cover only classes with changes in current deployment bundle.

Is there something similar when it comes to managed package upload? What other options do we have to speed up upload process and tests execution? Do we really need to have > 75% of coverage for beta packages or only for final majors?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I'm wondering if there is a way to bypass/suppress tests execution when uploading beta package.

No, 1GP (First Generation Packaging) always requires tests. This applies even to unmanaged packages.

> We'd like to have our beta version ready ASAP to install it in QA org, run smoke and start manual testing.

This is an ideal case for 2GP (Second Generation Packaging). You can install just the pieces you need, assuming you've organized your packages decently, *and* it doesn't require running tests for sandboxes, so installs take seconds-to-minutes instead of minutes-to-hours.

> And after that we might run apex tests post factum on packaging org to catch additional problems with logic.

You'd want to do this anyways, although uploading the 1GP will also trigger these tests when you're ready.

> Is there something similar when it comes to managed package upload?

No, the tests will always be required on upload.

> Do we really need to have > 75% of coverage for beta packages or only for final majors?

You always need 75% coverage or greater, as well as no failed unit tests. Using 2GP will greatly reduce the amount of time you spend running tests unnecessarily.